# Removing Bundlore malware manually

Tags: macos, mojave, malware

I have a MacBook Pro with macOS Mojave. My Sophos antivirus software found a 'Bundlore' malware and I need to remove it manually.

It says it's located in: `/Volumes/Player/Player_440.app/Contents/MacOS/RucSD0QPeG1Amuk`

However, I can't find the location and I have tried different methods so far. Thanks for yout help!

Answer (score 1):

The Bundlore adware is a collection of related adware programs with widely varying names, but that all appear to be made by the same group.

It is actually a Windows malware.

Removal

Delete all of the following browser extensions that you find: Shopy Mate, FlashMall, Cinema-Plus Pro (and variants like CinemaPlus, CinemaPro, Cinema + HD, Cinema + Plus + or Cinema Ploos).

Then Move the following items to the trash.

```
/Applications/WebTools.app
/Applications/WebShopper.app
~/Applications/WebTools.app
~/Applications/WebShopper.app
/Library/cinemapro1-2/
~/Library/cinemapro1-2/
~/Library/WebTools/
~/Library/Application Support/webHelperApp/
~/Library/Application Support/WebShopper/
~/Library/LaunchAgents/WebServerSocketApp
~/Library/LaunchAgents/UpdateDownloder
~/Library/LaunchAgents/com.webhelper.plist
~/Library/LaunchAgents/com.webtools.update.agent.plist
~/Library/LaunchAgents/com.webtools.uninstaller.plist
```

If you find NONE of those files then the Malware has not installed, you just have the Installer.

[More Information here](http://www.thesafemac.com/arg-bundlore/)